# Cannot use mouse to select text of a text box when the text box is embedded in a SplitContainer

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a form contains a splitContainer. On the Panel2 of the splitContainer, I added another form, called form2. In form2 I have a text Box.

I can edit the textbox, I mean I can type on the text box. However, I cannot select text in the textbox using Mouse. Here is my Code.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.splitContainer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.form2 = new TestTextBox.Form2();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // splitContainer1
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.splitContainer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.splitContainer1.Name = "splitContainer1";
            // 
            // splitContainer1.Panel1
            // 
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            // 
            // splitContainer1.Panel2
            // 
            this.form2.TopLevel = false;
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(this.form2);
            this.splitContainer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(812, 347);
            this.splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = 438;
            this.splitContainer1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(94, 110);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(213, 20);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // form2
            // 
            this.form2.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(362, 313);
            this.form2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.form2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.form2.Name = "form2";
            this.form2.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            this.form2.Text = "Form2";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(812, 347);
            this.Controls.Add(this.splitContainer1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.splitContainer1.Panel1.PerformLayout();
            this.splitContainer1.Panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.splitContainer1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
```

form2 have a textBox. and I cannot select text of this textbox using mouse.
Anyone who knows this problem, please help me!

Answer (score 1):

> On the Panel2 of the splitContainer, I added another form

This is not the way a split container is supposed to be used. You can add a `panel` to the `panel2`, not a `Form`!

Comment: For some particular reasons, We have to add Forms to the panel2. So Can you give me other suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If you have to stick to using a form inside a panel for some reason, try to set the forms .toplevel to false, does it change anything?

If you really dont need to use a form, then convert the form to a usercontrol instead and add the usercontrol to the panel.

You will have focus problem when using forms this way. I dont think you even get Form.Focus() and maybe some other events this way...

**Maybe you will be helped by the example here, scroll down to:** [Add Forms as usercontrols](http://dotnetrix.co.uk/form.htm)

Comment: thank you stefan, your link is exactly what I'm looking for. Many thanks!